# Show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^p}$ converges for p > $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let    $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}{}$   be a convergent series of positive terms.

Show that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^p}$$

converges for p > $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: You can use either AM-GM inequality or Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Comment: @michaelrozenberg, please do not edit many questions in a row, as that makes the from page like a vision of Christmas Past.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez OK. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** by arithmetic-geometric mean, we have $$\frac {\sqrt{a_n}} {n^p} \leq a_n + \frac{1}{n^{2p}}.$$

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: Now this is a very nice hint-answer. +1